# How can I upload data gathered in my PowerShell as a .csv to Azure Blob storage account?

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am using my script here to gather various AAD information, and then I want to upload the output as a CSV file to Azure Blob Storage.

I have tried many ways to do this in the Set-AzStorageBlobContent cmdlet function, but nothing works. I have tried -Stream $csvStream (nope), -InputFile and -Content, all don't work.

I am expecting my blob storage account, when this script runs, to have a .csv file called testusers on it. Everything I try fails at the last command for Set-AzStorageBlobContent to process the content from stream.

```
# Create the CSV content for Users
$csvContent = "redacted`nredacted"

foreach ($output in $outputStrings) {
    $csvContent += "`n$output"
}
```

Then,Here is the problematic part of my script: here is the part to try to upload to blob storage, and this is the part I need help on please!!!

```
# Create a byte array from the CSV content
$csvBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($csvContent)

# Create a memory stream from the byte array
$csvStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$csvBytes)

# Set the context of the storage account
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Create the container if it doesn't exist
$null = New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Upload the CSV to Azure Blob Storage
$destinationBlobName = "testusers.csv"
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $destinationBlobName -Context $ctx -Force - $csvStream
```

Answer (score 0):

I exported the **Azure AD users information in the CSV file** like below:

[image]

To **upload data gathered in my PowerShell as a csv to Azure blob storage**, I used the below script:

```bash
$csvContent = "C:\Users\ruk\Downloads\azureaduers.csv"

foreach ($output in $outputStrings) {
    $csvContent += "`n$output"
}

$storageAccountKey = "StorageAccountKey"
$storageAccountName = "rukstoracc12"
$containerName = "ruk"

# Create a byte array from the CSV content
$csvBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($csvContent)

# Create a memory stream from the byte array
$csvStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$csvBytes)

# Set the context of the storage account
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Create the container if it doesn't exist
$null = New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Upload the CSV to Azure Blob Storage
$destinationBlobName = "testusers.csv"
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $destinationBlobName -Context $ctx -Force
```

[image]

> To resolve the issue, exclude **`-$csvStream`** parameter in  **Set-AzStorageBlobContent** command.

The ***CSV file got uploaded successfully in the Storage Account container*** successfully like below:

[image]